# How do I remove the black border of a textfield?

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I made a textfield in IB with the following settings:

- Borderstyle: RoundRect
- View's BG Color: Black, Opacity: 15%

The result is that the inside of the field is 15%, but there's a very thin visible border that isn't, and I want that removed. I've tried doing it in code like this:

```
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
textField.layer.cornerRadius = 10
textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:1.0,green:1.0,blue:1.0,alpha:0.15).CGColor
```

But this just puts the border on the inside covering the actual textfield.

*Textfield:*

[image]

Answer (score 6):

### Swift 3 / Swift 4

The simplest approach to achieving a border-free textfield is to change the style of the textfield.

#### Steps

1. Make a IBOutlet reference to the textfield.
2. Set the textfield's
   border style to none.

**Example Code**

```
// Reference
@IBOutlet var tf: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Email TextField: no border
    tf.borderStyle = .none
}
```

The Result

[image: Image of how to remove boarder for textfield in Swift 3 Swift 4]

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this:

```
textField.layer.borderWidth = 0
```

Additionally, from the screenshot, it seems that `textField.layer.cornerRadius = 10` is ignored, make sure that your `textField` property is connected to the actual `UITextField`.

Comment: In the screenshot I didn't use the code, just the IB stuff

Comment: You should be able to remove the border just with textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None. Can you post a screenshot of the TextField while the app is running?

Comment: Yeah, i know, but that removes everything, I just want the thin outside border removed

Comment: You can't remove it with the borderStyle setted to RoundedRect.

Answer (score 2):

Swift3

```
passwordTF.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
```

For me its working as well as

```
mobileNumberTF.borderStyle = .none
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried several ways to remove the broder by programmatically and other suggested ways but later figured out this is the only way it removes the border from UITextField. Just select in interface builder, Border Style option

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

self.nameTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;